# Trato de Compilar la app pero esta no logra abrirse

Tags: java, android-studio, error404

estoy intentando compilar mi aplicación y al momento de darle en correr programa este se cierra.
esta es la clase donde estoy tratando de hacer toda la función de mi app, estoy haciendo uso de web services como xampp para conectar a la base de datos estoy usando php.

el error que me arroja es este:

> 2020-06-12 20:38:00.640 17235-17235/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.racz.tienda, PID: 17235
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity >ComponentInfo{com.racz.tienda/com.racz.tienda.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to >invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' >on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void >android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
> at com.racz.tienda.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
> 2020-06-12 20:38:00.651 17235-17235/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17235 SIG: 9

mi clase principal:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtnomnre,txttipo,txtdescripcion,txtprecio;
    Button bingresar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtnomnre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
        txttipo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
        txtdescripcion=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdes);
        txtprecio=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtprecio);

        bingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarservicio("http://192.168.100.11/tienda/insertarp.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private void ejecutarservicio(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro Exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("nombre",txtnomnre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("tipo",txttipo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("descripcion",txtdescripcion.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("precio",txtprecio.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

me arroja un error el cual desconozco su solución, he tratado algunas formas las cuales vi pero no funcionan, espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

Les dejo también la clase del layout aquí abajo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtnombre"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/nombre"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.072" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txttipo"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/tipo"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtnombre"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdes"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/descripcion"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txttipo"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtprecio"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/precio"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtdes"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bingresar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/ingresar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.261"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtprecio"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/productos"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.371"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bingresar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtprecio"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.106" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, tu definiste un botón bingresar:

```
Button bingresar;
```

Y luego quieres asignarle un onClick handler:

```
bingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarservicio("http://192.168.100.11/tienda/insertarp.php");
            }
        });
```

Pero en ningún lado estas definiendo ese botón, como sí lo haces con los otros editTesxt. Al momento de asignar el listener, la variable `bingresar` es null, y por lo tanto te da NullPointerException como bien está mostrado en la excepción.
Tienes que definir el botón, así:

```
bingresar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bingresar);
```

Comment: si muchas gracias, lo note tiempo después jajaja, pero se agradece la ayuda

Comment: @RIICHH223 Por favor, si la respuesta te ha ayudado marcala con una ✔ a la izquierda de la respuesta. Gracias.